# Subtracting an object and then deleting the object used to subtract within python script

Tags: python

I am currently trying to create an object within python in order to subtract from another object. I did this using the GUI with no problem but when I try to use the same code within the script it doesn't seem to work.

```
import bpy

#Large Cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=2, location=(0, 0, 0))

#Small Cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, location=(0, -1.5, 0))

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].object = 
bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"]
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Boolean")
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
```

How can I select the Large Cube in order to use the boolean operation and then delete the Small Cube?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this with operators (`bpy.ops`) anyway...

Comment: Is there a better way to do it? I just want to know how to subtract an object in python and then delete the object used to subtract.

Comment: batFinger answered very well, and that's exactly what I was referring to. I'm sure there's a few hundred questions here about not using `bpy.ops`, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can add modifiers with `obj.modifiers.new(name, type)`.  When a primitive is added it is the context object.  Changing the order made the large_cube context object, otherwise it can be set with `context.scene.objects.active = large_cube`.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

#Small Cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, location=(0, -1.5, 0))
small_cube = context.object

#Large Cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=2, location=(0, 0, 0))
large_cube = context.object

mod = large_cube.modifiers.new("Boolean", type='BOOLEAN')
mod.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
mod.object = small_cube

# large cube has context.
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=mod.name)

context.scene.objects.unlink(small_cube)
bpy.data.objects.remove(small_cube)
```

Comment: Wow that makes a lot more sense. The only problem I am getting now is I just copy and pasted that into blender but I came up with an error for the last line of code that says "Python script fail, look in the console for now..." I apologize for asking a second question but after toiling with it for a bit it was obvious I had no idea what I was doing. Mind helping one last time?

Comment: What version of blender are you using?  Made an edit to unlink small_cube from scene before removing.  Newer versions do this for you by default.

Comment: I am using version 2.76.

Comment: Just got it with the edit. Thank you very much